# c++ Как из вектора изьять значение

Tags: c++, vector

Я с++ учу примерно месяца 4-5. Много, очень много чего не знаю, и порошу о помощи)

Есть структура. Структура хранить в себе float x, float y, float width, float height

```
struct Object
{
    vector <float> obj_x;                    //Начало обьекта по Х
    vector <float> obj_y;                    //Начало обьекта по У
    vector <float> obj_width;                //Длина обьекта по Х
    vector <float> obj_height;               //Длина обьекта по У
};
Object object;                      //Инизилизация обьектов
```

Есть вектор, котоорый хранит структуру

```
vector <Object> vector_object
```

из файла xml я записываю все координаты в структуру, ну а структура нахрдится в векторе. С этим проблем нет.

Но в дальнейшем мне нужно сравнить x со значением из структуры, к примеру:

```
if (x > vector_object[1].obj_x)
```

Компилятор ругается. В поисках истины, понял что нужно перегрузить оператор >. Там же в гугле нашел что то типо этого

```
float x(const float x)
{
    return x > vector_object[x].obj_x;
}
```

но это получается замкнутый круг. Как я могу вернуть значение если мне опять необходимо сравнить значения?))

Помогите пожалуйста, и не ругайте сильно.

Полный файл [Map.h файл считывает xml...](https://github.com/Guselnikov-Maks/game/blob/master/map/Map.h)

Comment: и что по вашему должно быть в результате сравнения `float`(если я правильно понял тип `x`) с `vector<float>`? К чему относилось найденное в гугле `float x(const float x)...`  я вообще не понимаю

Comment: Вам точно нужны вектора в объекте? У вас получается, что *один* объект имеет *много* координат и размеров? (при этом еще и не связанных между собой - координат `x` может быть, например, большее количество, чем координат `y`)

Comment: vector_object[1].obj_x  является вектором, а х  это float.  И как вы сравниваете тип с контейнером этого типа?

Comment: Есть объект, у него есть начальная координата х и у и длина и высота. Один вестор это один объект которых хранит все 4 свойства. Я хочу сравнить  другие координаты с координатами объекта. И если другой объект попал в в этот то выполнить действие. Для этого мне нужно сравнить.

Comment: `Один вестор это один объект которых хранит все 4 свойства`, перефразируйте это как-то, ничего не понятно. У вас `Object` содержит 4 вектора, что в них хранится? Судя по вашим комментариям в коде, это должно быть 1 значение, а не вектор значений

Comment: Сейчас попробую подробно объяснить

Comment: Сейчас попробую подробно объяснить.                           В файле tmx есть группа объектов, которые хранят в себе 4 координаты. Я сделал структуру в которой 4 float, а вектор хранит в себе структуру. Если первый объект имеет координаты x = 10; y = 20; width = 50; height = 100; то vector_object[0].x выведет 10 vector_object[0].y выведет 20 и так далее. Я думал сделать динамический масив который будет хранить все все эти данные но тогда мне нужно будет иметь 4 массива и по всем им проходить. Если можно, подскажите, как можно хранить 4 значения  одного объекта. Объектов может быть много

Comment: вы используете структуру , заносите в нее данные  - дак считаите ваши координаты сразу  - для высоты по x и ширины по y  
в результате будете сравнивать два диапазона  - по х от точки до точки . и по y от точки до точки . вы слишком мудрите , как  мне кажется  
и вам же говорят уже несколько раз - к чему вектора у вас в структуре  - вам нужно сохранить всего лишь  координаты